# TSQL Grouping Dataset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, grouping

Currently I have dataset as below:-

[image: AsIs Grouping dataset]

I would like to calculate GroupRanking based on RegionalManager as shown below:-

[image: ToBE Grouping]

It would be great, if someone can help to resolve the issue

**Note:** I am using SQL 2008 R2

Comment: Not sure why your storerank changed between the two examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:-

```
select
    RegionalManager,
    StoreName,
    StoreRank,
    rank() over(partition by RegionalManager order by StoreRank) 
from #dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

If your first dataset is represented by the query

```
SELECT
  RegionalManager,
  StoreName,
  StoreRank
FROM
  #Stores
```

Then the second result can be done with this query

```
SELECT
  RegionalManager,
  StoreName,
  StoreRank,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RegionalManager ORDER BY StoreRank ASC) AS 'GroupRank'
FROM
  #Stores
```

Mat Richardson appears to have given the same answer, using the function RANK() rather than ROW_NUMBER().  RANK() will give ties, i.e. 2 groups can have the same rank, while ROW_NUMBER() will not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Row_number` or `Rank` or `Dense_Rank` alone is good enough to get the result.

```
SELECT
  RegionalManager,
  StoreName,
  StoreRank,
((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StoreRank ASC) - 1 ) / 3 ) + 1  AS GroupRank
FROM
  Yourtable
 order by RegionalManager,StoreName.
```

As mentioned in comments not sure why your storerank changed between the sample data and expected result

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b159f/5)